# Google maps with "local search engine" how to show all results

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Google maps with "local search engine" how to show all results.

It displays only 4 results, but I want to see all results.
I tried this:

```
  var options = new google.search.SearcherOptions(); // create the object
  searcher.setResultSetSize(GSearch.LARGE_RESULTSET/*google.search.Search.LARGE_RESULTSET*/);
      options.setExpandMode(google.search.SearchControl.EXPAND_MODE_CLOSED);
```

But it didn't help me.
You can download an example from this URL: http://kliuev.com/map.html

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: Sorry for that, I just used jquery for working with some parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what you mean by "local search engine." Do you mean your own private search engine? In which case this might be a useful article as a model:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3.html

Or do you mean use Google's local search? Which is now called Places, and here's a good reference for that:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html#places_autocomplete

Comment: No, I meant exactly local search engine: http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/maps/documentation/localsearch/

Comment: So the second case as you described, yes, I meant about Google's local search

Comment: Local search is deprecated, you should use Places

Comment: You can display a maximum of 20 results per request.

Comment: Thank you, but could you help me how to do it,please.

Comment: Here are two different samples you could look at the source for: http://mano-demos.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/slides/gddplaces2011-de/Geo-Places-API/places-search-dynamic.html 

http://mano-demos.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/slides/gddplaces2011-de/Geo-Places-API/places-search-simple.html